# continuous integration with drone and github: build is not triggering on commit

Tags: continuous-integration, drone.io

I'm using [open source edition](https://github.com/drone/drone) of drone.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'

services:
  drone-server:
    image: drone/drone:0.5
    ports:
     - 80:8000
    volumes:
     - ./drone:/var/lib/drone/
    restart: always
    environment:
     - DRONE_OPEN=true
     - DRONE_ADMIN=khataev
     - DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT=github-client-string
     - DRONE_GITHUB_SECRET=github-secret-string
     - DRONE_SECRET=drone-secret-string

  drone-agent:
    image: drone/drone:0.5
    command: agent
    restart: always
    depends_on: [ drone-server ]
    volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
     - DRONE_SERVER=ws://drone-server:8000/ws/broker
     - DRONE_SECRET=drone-secret-string
```

Application is registered and authorized on Github and secret/client strings are provided.

I placed .drone.yml file into my project repository:

```
pipeline:
  build:
    image: rails-qna
    commands: 
      - bundle exec rake db:drop
      - bundle exec rake db:create
      - bundle exec rake db:migrate
      - bundle exec rspec
```

Screenshots of project [settings](http://screenshot.ru/upload/image/zktp) and builds [status](http://screenshot.ru/upload/image/zktg)
1) What I've missed, why build is not triggering by commit to repo?
2) How to trigger build manually?
3) What is **Timeout** in project settings?

Answer (score 0):

Found an issue - github webhooks could not reach my drone server due network settings.